# How to iterate through all PHP Imap Folders without opening new Connections

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to search through my entire inbox with the `PHP Imap Library`, using `imap_search()`

I am using imap_open() to open the stream for each folder, but the issue is that servers like hotmail block you after 6 or 7 tries, so I need to be able to switch through folders without opening a new connection stream.

This is the current code I use to connect to each folder.
$server is something like

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX';
if($connection = imap_open($server,$login,$password))
```

Answer (score 4):

See [imap_reopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-reopen.php)

Update: You may also be interested in [imap_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php)